# How do I read and change the value of a TEdit control?

Tags: delphi

I have a Form `TForm1` having 5 `TEdit` and 2 `TBitBtn`.

I also need the Program so that after inputting Numeric Data in `Edit1` and `Edit2` on `BitBtn1Click`, `Edit1` and `Edit2` value will summed and will be displayed in `Edit3`.

Comment: You don't need to tell us your name in your question. It's right there underneath the question. Also, I added the generic delphi tag, in addition to the delphi-xe2 tag because that will get your question in front of more potential answerers. Finally, please do not put download links in the question. We don't want to download things. Put the code in the question and format it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
var
  val1, val2, sum: Integer;
...
val1 := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
val2 := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
sum := val1 + val2;
Edit3.Text := IntToStr(sum);
```

If you want floating point arithmetic do it like this

```
var
  val1, val2, sum: Double;
...
val1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
val2 := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
sum := val1 + val2;
Edit3.Text := FloatToStr(sum);
```

Answer (score 4):

To read and set the value of a TEdit control, you simply reference the `Text` property of the control. The Text property is of type String.

Since Text is a String property, you can treat it in your code as a String variable. You can pass it into a function that expects a String constant:

```
// Edit1 is the name of the TEdit control
// Display the value in the edit control to the user
ShowMessage(Edit1.Text);
```

You can assign it to a String variable with a simple assignment:

```
var
  // My string variable
  myString: String;
begin
  // Edit1 is the Name of the control
  myString := Edit1.Text;
end;
```

To set the value of a TEdit control, you simply assign a string to the Text property. This could be a String constant:

```
Edit1.Text := 'hello';
```

Or it could be from a String variable:

```
Edit1.Text := myString;
```

Math is done on numeric types, so for arithmetic, you'll need to use a function to convert the string values into numbers.

For Integer arithmetic, you can use `StrToInt()` or `StrToIntDef()`:

```
var
  myInteger: Integer;
begin
  // Convert Edit1.Text string to a number and assign to numeric type for math
  // If the value in Edit1.Text cannot be converted, an exception will be raised
  myInteger := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

Using `StrToIntDef()`:

```
var
  myInteger: Integer;
begin
  // If Edit1.Text cannot be converted, the default value of 0 will be used
  myInteger := StrToIntDef(Edit1.Text, 0);
end;
```

For floating point arithmetic, use `StrToFloat()` or `StrToFloatDef()` instead.

To assign an Integer back to the Text property, you'll need to convert the Integer to a String before you assign it:

```
var
  myInteger: Integer;
begin
  myInteger := 12;
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(myInteger);
end;
```

For floating points, use `FloatToStr()`.

Finally, to put everything together, to get the numeric values of two edit boxes and display the sum in a third edit box, simply do this:

```
var
  // Floating point variables
  value1: Real;
  value2: Real;
  sum: Real;
begin
  // Get the values from the edit boxes, converting them to floating point types
  value1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  value2 := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  // Sum them
  sum := value1 + value2;
  // Convert the sum to string and assign back to edit box
  Edit3.Text := FloatToStr(sum);
end;
```

Or in one step:

```
Edit3.Text := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(Edit1.Text) + StrToFloat(Edit2.Text));
```

Comment: you forgot to put in try..except statements to check for non-numeric input.

Comment: @Johan, it was intentional, though I did warn of the exception. Keeping it simple.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the following snippet:

> so that after inputting Numeric Data in Edit1 and Edit2

If you want to only allow Numeric data, it's a good idea to disallow non numeric data in the edit boxes.
Here's how to do that.

```
const
 TabKey = #9;
 Backspace = #8;
 Enter = #13;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not (Key in ['0'..'9','-',TabKey,Enter,Backspace]) then Key:= #0; //integers
  //realnumbers: if not (Key in ['0'..'9','-','e','E','.',TabKey,Enter,Backspace]) then Key:= #0;
end;
```

If you only have integer data, this will do, if you have scientific numbers, you need to do some testing for the letter `e` and the decimal point as well to allow for irrational numbers.
Regardless of what you do it's a good idea to check to see the input is a valid number and let the user know.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyEdit: TEdit;
  OtherEdit: TEdit;
  TryNumber: double; 
  OtherNumber: double; 
  Success: boolean;
begin
  Success:= true;
  if (Sender is TEdit) then begin
    MyEdit:= TEdit(Sender);
    try
      if MyEdit.Text = '' then TryNumber:= 0
      else TryNumber:= StrToFloat(MyEdit.Text);
      MyEdit.Color:= clWindow; //all is OK make edit standard white.
      MyEdit.Hint:= '';
    except  
      MyEdit.Color:= clRed;  //Let the user know the output will not compute.
      MyEdit.Hint:= MyEdit.Text + ' is not a valid number '; 
      Success:= false;
    end; 
  end;
  if (MyEdit = Edit1) then OtherEdit:= Edit2
  else OtherEdit:= Edit1;
  try
    if OtherText.Text = '' then OtherNumber:= 0
    else OtherNumber:= StrToFloat(OtherEdit.Text);
  except 
    Success:= false;
  end;
  if Success then Edit3.Text:= FloatToStr(TryNumber + OtherNumber); 
end;
```

Note that you can attach this Event to both `Edit1` and `Edit2`, so you do not have to write the code twice. (But I'm sure you already knew that).

[image] (Both edit's share the same event).

**Important things to remember**

- Always use `try..except` to catch errors so that your program does not break with an error, see: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Exceptions
- If you have an editbox that only allows numeric data, consider using a `maskedit` which only allows valid chars, or code your own filter (if it's trivial to do so).
- Try and use a single routine for multiple controls, so you don't end up with multiple very similar routines that all do almost the same thing. That way if you change something, you'll only have to change it in **one** place and it will work in all the controls that make use of that routine.

Comment: I like the color approach. I often prevent them from even entering non-numeric characters via OnKeyDown, which is a bit harsher.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I use the "no alpha's" in numeric fields as well, but that does not prevent a user from entering `1254-121-1512`  in a field meant for pure integer data.

Comment: It can get complicated. I also use TSpinEdit a lot.

Comment: Or you can use [`TryStrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/SysUtils.TryStrToFloat) and you can omit the `try..except` machinery ;)