# Change a record property with a variable/dynamic name

Tags: delphi, field, record

I have a simple Delphi record:

```
type
   TCustomer = record
     name : string[30];
     age  : byte;
end;
```

And I know I can set this record's field by hard coding the field name in code:

```
 var
   customer : TCustomer;

 begin
   // Set up our customer record
   customer.name := 'Fred Bloggs';
   customer.age  := 23;
 end;
```

But I have a single `TEdit`, a single `TComboBox` next to it, and a single `TButton`. The combobox is fixed and has two items, "Name" and "Age". It will first be set to "Name". User types their name value into the edit box. The is a Save type of button that would have an OnClick event like:

```
procedure TMainForm.SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(MyComboBox.Text = 'Name') then
  begin
    customer.name := MyEditBox.Text;
  end
  else
  begin
    customer.age := MyEditBox.Text;
  end;

end;
```

The record was initialized someplace else. What I'm getting at here is in my cases there are 101 possible combobox items. Should I make a massive case statement to handle this or can I consolidate the code by matching the reorder's field name to a dynamic piece of information being set by another control (in this case a combobox)?

Comment: Where did you put that line of code?

Comment: Also, possibly a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538205/how-do-i-read-and-change-the-value-of-a-tedit-control/8539468#8539468)

Comment: You can use RTTI but probably not with those short strings from the last century. Seriously, what's with the short strings?

Comment: This example came from here http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Records

Comment: This is an example where DelphiBasics is giving you sample code that should have been buried 100 feet deep in the ground, as it belongs to about 1984. In 2014 we use Classes and generics, and we do not use short-strings ( string[30] ) in records.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Delphi Version that has enhanced RTTI (Delphi 2010 and higher) you can do it.

However there are a few traps:

1.Short strings have to defined as type for the compiler to create typeinfo for these fields (as I did with the `String30`)

2.`TValue` which is the type to carry things around in the enhanced RTTI does not automatic type conversion (like the string from the edit into the Integer for the Age field). That is why I took the way into a `Variant` and converted that into the correct type for the field (just for `ShortString` and `Integer`, the rest is left as an exercise to the reader).

3.`TValue` does not like conversions from different `ShortString` types (`String30` is not the same as `ShortString`) that is why I used `TValue.Make`. What is missing there is a check if the provided value matches the type (like it it exceeds 30 chars). Also it of course is not unicode compatible.

```
uses
  Rtti,
  TypInfo;

type
  String30 = string[30];

  TCustomer = record
    name: String30;
    age: byte;
  end;

var
  c: TCustomer;

function CastFromVariant(ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo; const AValue: Variant): TValue;
var
  asShort: ShortString;
begin
  case ATypeInfo.Kind of
    tkInteger: Result := TValue.From<Integer>(AValue);
    tkString:
    begin
      asShort := AValue;
      TValue.Make(@asShort, ATypeInfo, Result);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiType;
  f: TRttiField;
  v: TValue;
begin
  t := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TCustomer));
  f := t.GetField(ComboBox1.Text);
  v := CastFromVariant(f.FieldType.Handle, Edit1.Text);
  f.SetValue(@c, v);
end;

procedure TForm5.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiType;
  f: TRttiField;
  v: TValue;
begin
  t := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TCustomer));
  f := t.GetField(ComboBox1.Text);
  v := f.GetValue(@c);
  Edit1.Text := v.ToString;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The on-screen components are their own variables. They exist independently of your records.

You need to copy from one to the other as needed.

(Use my code as a guide -- it may not be exactly correct syntactically.)

```
// UI component declarations within the form
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  . . .
  cbo : TComboBox;
  edt : TEdit;
  . . .
end;
. . .
var
  Form1 : TForm1;
. . .
// to copy values from customer to UI components:
cbo.ItemIndex := customer.age; // assuming this is what the combobox is used for, 
                               // and it starts at zero
edt := customer.name;

// to copy from UI components into customer, you'll need to do it inside of one 
// of the event handlers. 
TForm1.cboCloseUp( sender : TObject ); // the onCloseUp handler, when the combo drop-down closes
begin
  customer.age := cbo.ItemIndex; // or StrToInt(cbo.Text)
end;

TForm1.edtChange( sender : TObject );  // the onChange handler whenever the edit changes
begin
  customer.name := edt.Text;
end;
```

That's the gist of it. If the ages in the combobox don't start at zero, then you'll want to adjust the offset accordingly when you copy bewteen the customer record and the combobox. You can either set ItemIndex+offset if the values are linear, or simply write a value into cbo.Text.

Comment: Depending on how it's being used, it might also be better to do the copy from the UI back to the record when the record data is needed instead of every single time the UI changes.

Comment: Of course, there are many variations depending on how it's being used, which the OP didn't explain ... this is just one example. I think the thing that the OP was missing is that the UI components have their own storage that's independent of what his records offer. There are UI frameworks where you have to supply the variables where the UI components actually store the values -- Delphi doesn't do that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wants to select in the `TComboBox` which field in the record he wants to edit in the `TEdit`.

Comment: It looks like the OP changed the question since I posted my answer.

Comment: @Stefan's comment is equally valid for all revisions of the question